# Installing old .pkg update file on PS4

Tags: ps4, networking

I have the original, vanilla release disk of a game but don't want to update to the latest version.

I have a particular version of that game that I really liked and would like to install the update package that I've found on internet.

So far I have managed to block the automatic update of that game by setting-up the proxy server on my local network and filtering the update url so it is locked to the vanilla.
(The proxy server is called 'tinyproxy-ogra' running on Ubuntu Core on Raspberry PI on my local network, but could possibly install something else on either the respi or mac.)

I was wondering if it is possible to **redirect** the url the PS4 is trying to open `something.playstation.something.json` rather than block it, so I could redirect it to e. g. my local network (I've got the Apache up and running) and download and install my old update file instead of the latest.